# TensorFlow model server - Could not resolve host POST

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am new to TensorFlow (using 1.13) and trying to build a TF model and serve it on a docker tensor flow model server.
I have exported my model, installed docker and started my docker container with the command:

docker run -p 8501:8501 --name SN_TFlow 
--mount type=bind,source=/tmp/service_model/export,target=/models 
-e MODEL_NAME=1596551653 -t tensorflow/serving &

I can see my container running and the line: "I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:375] Exporting HTTP/REST API at:localhost:8501 ..." in the client which seems to indicate all is up and running according to the doc.

[image: Docker log view]

However when I try to test my model with the curl command:
$ curl -d ‘{"test_value": [40]}' \ -X POST http://localhost:8501/1/models/1596551653:predict

I get a message saying:
URL bad/illegal format or missing url
Could not resolve host POST
and I get a 404 message.

[image]
I also tried simply curl http://localhost:8501/models/1/1596551653 but also get Not found.
Any idea what I am missing? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem I observe in your code is the **`\`** in the middle of the **`curl`** command.

The **`backslash`**, **`\`** should occur at the end of the line, if the command is more than one line.

So, the below command,

```
$ curl -d ‘{"test_value": [40]}' \ -X POST

http://localhost:8501/1/models/1596551653:predict
```

should be changed as shown below (move the **`backslash`** to the end) :

```
$ curl -d ‘{"test_value": [40]}' -X POST \

http://localhost:8501/1/models/1596551653:predict
```

Also, we suggest you to upgrade to the Latest Version of **`Tensorflow`** in **`1.x`**, which is **`1.15`** or to **`2.3.0`**.